# How to look for following problem in Ring theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain such that every non zero prime ideal is maximal in $R[x]$. Choose the correct statement.

a) $R$ is a Field.

b) $R$ contains $\mathbb Z$ as a subring

c) $R$ contains $F_p$ as a subring for some prime $p$

Now I think c) is false clearly because taking $R$ as $\mathbb Q$  then c is out.  But do not know further how to look for others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed a is the correct choice. If $R$ is not a field, then it contains a nonzero proper ideal $I$.  $I+(x)$ is then a proper ideal of $R[x]$, while $(x)$ is a prime ideal properly contained in $I+(x)$.